# An application of the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I'm recalling this question from memory, so I may be messing it up a bit.

Let $a/3+b/2+c=0$.  Show that $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has at least one root in $[0,1]$ using the Mean Value Theorem.

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bc+c$.  Then $f(0)=c$ and $f(1)=a+b+c$.  Also $f'(x)=2ax+b$.  So there exists $f(\xi)=[f(1)-f(0)]/1=a+b-c$.  Then $a+b-c=2a\xi+b \Rightarrow (a-c)/2a=\xi$.

I'm not sure if this is right or where to go from here.

Comment: Just a quick note: you presumably mean $f(1) = a + b + c$.

Comment: @ortl: typo in third paragraph $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ (not $f(x)=ax^2+bc+c$) and $f(1)-f(0)=a+b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if $a =0$, then we have $bx + c = 0 \implies x = - \frac{c}{b} = \frac{b/2}{b} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Now, suppose $a \neq 0$.
Note that $c = - \frac{a}{3} - \frac{b}{2}$, so you want to prove that the function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx - \frac{a}{3} - \frac{b}{2}$ has a root in $[0,1]$.  We have $f(0) = - \frac{a}{3} - \frac{b}{2}$ and $f(1) =  \frac{2}{3} a + \frac{1}{2} b$.  Note that 
$$f(0)\cdot f(1) = - \frac{2}{9}a^2 - \frac{1}{4}b^2 < 0$$ as $a \neq 0$.  Thus, $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ have different signs, and by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is a root in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Two quick comments when I look back at my answer.  This is false if $a = b  =0$ and $c \neq 0$.  Also, my method was to use the Intermediate Value Theorem rather than the Mean Value Theorem, so to may not be quite the answer you were looking for.

Comment: $f(0)\cdot f(1) = - \frac{2}{9}a^2 - \frac{1}{2}ab - \frac{1}{4}b^2$, so $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ don't necessarily have different signs.

Answer (score 5):

Apply MVT to $g(x) = \int (ax^2+bx+c) dx$.

Comment: I don't follow.  My analysis class stopped at differentiation, so I can't utilize the FTC.

Comment: @jdla: $\int(ax^2+bx+c)dx=\frac{a}{3}x^3+\frac{b}{2}x^2+cx$

Comment: @jdla You don't need the fundamental theorem of calculus, as you can calculate the integral *explicitly*, as Pambos points out.

Comment: Ah sorry.  I was for some reason viewing it as the $\int f'(x)$.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a definite integral to define $g$.

Comment: Actually...would this be "cheating."  In my analysis class I still don't have the foresight of knowing what integration is.

Comment: Does this prove that there is a unique root in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @TomOldfield Surely not, but the "exactly one root" bit is wrong in the first place. Counterexample: $6x^2-6x+1=0$, whose two roots are $\frac12\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @jdla About cheating, ... this is a good question that I have no answer, but +1 for your academic integrity.

Comment: @user1551:  The OP changed his post to "at least one real root" so it looks like your answer should do the trick.